# Externalizing parameters for VS2008 C++ project compilation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, externalizing

Is there some way to externalize the paths of libraries that are used in the compilation process on Visual Studio 2008? Like, *.properties files?

My goal is to define "variables" referencing locations to headers files and libraries, like *.properties files are used in the Ant build system for Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`.vsprops`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4xbdz1e.aspx) files. They're comparable to the *.properties files.

Answer (score 2):

Environment Variables?

All the $(xyz) replacements allowed in the propertier are, and you are allowed to "bring your own".

They are normally inherited from the parent process, so you can set them

- for the machine / user in the system settings (usually inherited via explorer)
- in a batch file that sets them before running devenv.exe
- in an addin like **[SolutionBuildEnvironment](http://workspacewhiz.com/SolutionBuildEnvironmentReadme.html)** to read them from a project file

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to influencing the location of #includes, Project properties|Configuration Properties|C/C++/Additional Include Directories is the ticket. There is also project properties|Common Properties|Additional reference search paths.

If your question is how do I parameterize stuff in a VCProj file like I would in Ant, the answer is that in VS2010 VC projects are[/can?] be MSBuild-based whereas VS2008 vcproj files are a proprietary XML based format [but as the other answers say, they have an analogous properties capability].

In the absence of more info, I'm pretty sure the standard approach for what you're doing is to add your search paths a la the first or second paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how Ant works, but for your static libraries and headers you can edit the `.vcproj` file. These are XML files in fact. Libraries go in the *VCLinkerTool* tool tag, in *AdditionalDependencies*

```
<Tool
    Name="VCLinkerTool"
    AdditionalOptions=" /subsystem:windowsce,5.01"
    AdditionalDependencies="iphlpapi.lib commctrl.lib coredll.lib"
/>
```

Additional header paths are defined in the *VCCLCompilerTool* tool tag, in *AdditionalIncludeDirectories*

```
<Tool
    Name="VCCLCompilerTool"
    Optimization="0"
    AdditionalIncludeDirectories="dev\mydir"
    PreprocessorDefinitions="WIN32;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE"
/>
```

Be careful, there is one such section for each build configuration.
Is this what you are looking for?

Edit : the `.vsprops` suggested by MSalters are more powerful; you can define additional dependencies and libraries in them an make your projects inherit these properties. Well I learned something useful today!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a build system like [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/).  You give CMake a high-level description of your project, and it spits out the necessary files to get your project to build correctly via another tool (e.g. Visual Studio's IDE, or a Unix-style makefile).

**Paths:** You can use CMake's `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES()` and `LINK_DIRECTORIES()` commands in the CMakeList.txt configuration file to specify these paths.  CMake has *variables* which describe both aspects of your environment (many of which can be autodiscovered, e.g. `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` which is the command to run your C compiler) plus any options you wish to allow the user to specify directly.  All variables are stored in a separate plain text configuration file, CMakeCache.txt, that can be edited in a text editor or using a special GUI configuration tool.

CMake has many other features, like the ability to autodiscover the locations of many useful libraries, and to produce customised source/header files from "template" files containing CMake directives using the `CONFIGURE_FILE()` command.

**Advantages:**

- Highly portable across common environments (e.g. it can produce solution files for several versions of MS Visual C++, as well as makefiles for Unix (e.g. Linux) systems).
- Used by several large multiplatform projects (e.g. KDE)
- Very simple to set up simple projects
- I've found the dependency checking system to be rock-solid -- e.g. it knows to rebuild if you change compiler options (unlike naive use of `make` for example)

**Disadvantages:**

- Ugly, primitive syntax
- Documentation quality varies (e.g. it's sometimes hard to tell exactly what properties affect any given object)
- Some time investment involved